# Finding the intersection of a pencil of lines with a plane and making a 3D plot of the ensemble

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I've computed the intersection of a plane with some lines. It looks OK until I try to make a 3D graph from *intersec_lines*.

```
alpha = Pi/5;
r1 = 5;
r2 = 2;
h = 3;
n = 20;
plane = InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 0}, {Cos[alpha], 0, Sin[alpha]}, {0, 1, 0}}];
lines = 
  Table[
    InfiniteLine[
      {r1*Cos[2*Pi*x/n], r1*Sin[2*Pi*x/n], 0}, 
      {r2*Cos[2*Pi*x/n], r2*Sin[2*Pi*x/n], h}], 
   {x, n}];
intersec_points = NSolve[{x, y, z} ∈ plane && {x, y, z} ∈ #]& /@ lines
```

Does anyone know how to do it? It seem it should be pretty basic, but I'm just starting to use Mathematica.

Comment: Do not use `_` in variable names, since `_` has a special meaning in *Mathematica*.

Comment: To make it even clearer: Your code works except the variable named in not allowed because it has "_" in it. Then you have to write `{x,y,z} /. Flatten[intersecPoints, 1]` to get a list of points.

Answer (score 6):

Using `RegionIntersection[]` is the most straightforward route for finding the intersection points:

```
With[{α = π/5, r1 = 5, r2 = 2, h = 3, n = 20},
     plane = InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 0}, {Cos[α], 0, Sin[α]}, {0, 1, 0}}];
     lines = Table[InfiniteLine[{r1 Cos[2 π x/n], r1 Sin[2 π x/n], 0},
                                {r2 Cos[2 π x/n], r2 Sin[2 π x/n], h}], {x, n}];]

pts = RegionIntersection[plane, #] & /@ lines;

Graphics3D[{plane, lines, Sphere[#, 1/4] & @@@ pts}, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> 10]
```

[image: intersection points of a cone and a plane]